# localStorage is not defined - Recoil with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, recoiljs

I'm using a `localstorage` effect as per the [Recoil docs](https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/atom-effects/#local-storage-persistence), but when i run my app i get a `localStorage is not defined` error in the browser. My first assumption would be that this is not running in the browser and the server instead. I don't think this is the case, unless Next.js is doing something funky under the hood?

Here's my code:

`project/recoil/atom.ts`

```
const localStorageEffect = (key: string) => ({setSelf, onSet}: {setSelf: any, onSet: any}) => {
  const savedValue = localStorage.getItem(key)
  if (savedValue != null) {
    setSelf(JSON.parse(savedValue));
  }

  onSet((newValue: any, _: null, isReset: any) => {
    isReset
      ? localStorage.removeItem(key)
      : localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
  });
};

export const userAtom = atom({
  key: 'userAtom',
  default: {},
  effects: [
    localStorageEffect('user'),
  ]
});
```

I'm trying to use it to persist login state. Here's one example of where I'm using it:

`project/pages/login.tsx`

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const setUser = useSetRecoilState(userAtom);
  const setIsAuthed = useSetRecoilState(isAuthedAtom);

  const submitHandler = async (e: any) => {
    try {
      const walletInfo = await fetchWallet(address);
      setIsAuthed(true);
      setUser({...walletInfo, address});
      
    } catch(e: any) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Login address={address} setAddress={setAddress} submitHandler={submitHandler} />
  )
```

Here's `_app.tsx`:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import {
  RecoilRoot
} from 'recoil';
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

However, upon loading the homepage nothing will render because of the error message. I've read that a solution would be to run this in a useEffect hook, however i cannot do this since my effect is defined in `atoms.ts` and cannot be moved. Is there a way to force this file to ran in the browser?

Comment: "The issue you are seeing is because localStorage (aka window.localStorage) is not defined on the server side. Next server renders your components, so when that happens and it tried to access localStorage it can't find it. You'll have to wait until the browser renders it in order to use localStorage."

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19911

Answer (score 3):

Here you can try this. Worked for me

```
import { recoilPersist } from 'recoil-persist'


const localStorage = typeof window !== `undefined` ? window.localStorage : null

const { persistAtom } = recoilPersist({
    key: 'recoil-persist',
    storage: localStorage
})

export const darkModeState = atom<true | false >({
    key: 'darkMode',
    default: false,
    effects_UNSTABLE: [persistAtom]
})
```

Comment: Worked for me with recoil-persist.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any other libraries, just replace this part:

```js
import { AtomEffect } from 'recoil';

const store = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage : null;

export const localStorageEffect: (key: string) => AtomEffect<any> =
  (key) =>
  ({ setSelf, onSet }) => {
    if (store) {
      const savedValue = store.getItem(key);
      if (savedValue != null) {
        setSelf(JSON.parse(savedValue));
      }

      onSet((newValue, _, isReset) => {
        isReset ? store.removeItem(key) : store.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
      });
    }
  };
```